# Client not ready yet

Tags: android

I'm new to programming and I need help, every time I try to run my app it keeps loading and nothing is happening, how can I fix this?

```
$ adb shell am start \
  -n com.myapplication/com.myapplication.ui.base.MainFragementActivity" \
  -a android.intent.action.MAIN \
  -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 

Client not ready yet...waiting for process to come online
```

[image]

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.myapplication.ui.base.MainFragmentActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="myapplication">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Delete the Emulator and create again.

Comment: I tried running the app on my mobile and still got the same response, it kept on loading

Comment: Can you show the code? @jack

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: try to remove android:lauch mode and exported and then build and run the app @jack

Comment: sorry but that dint work :/ @Ankur_009

Comment: then paste activity code.@JAck

Comment: I do not have any Java activity class for My MainFragnentActivity, i only have the XML code above @Ankur_009

Comment: That is written in Manifest.xml file? Please copy paste the  MainFragmentActivity class content.

Comment: I do not have a class for the MainFragmentActivity @Ankur_009

Comment: Then how could you add here?  please go through the basic of Android or read others code. @Jack

Comment: I am facing a similar issue.  Did you find a solution?